# Functional equation involving integral

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-equations, integral-equations

> Find $f(x)$ given that it satisfies the equation $f(x) = x^2 + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \sin(x+1) dt$

---

### My attempt:

Let $\int_0^{\pi/2}f(t)dt=c$

So

$$f(x)=x^2+c\sin(x+1)$$

Integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2dx+c\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x+1)dx$$

$$c=\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-c(\cos(x+1))\bigg|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

$$c=\frac{\pi^3}{24}+c(\sin(1)+\cos(1))$$

$$\implies c=\frac{\pi^3}{24(1-\sin1-\cos1)}$$

Plugging it back we obtain:

$$f(x)=x^2+\frac{\pi^3\sin(x+1)}{24(1-\sin1-\cos1)}$$

This however doesn't seem to match with the given answer:

$$f(x) = x^2-\frac {2(3\pi^2-4\pi-8)}{\pi^2-4}\sin x-\frac {\pi^3-16}{\pi^2-4} \cos x$$

I have tried expanding $\sin(x+1)$ in my expression but it didn't lead to anything.

Are these expressions equivalent? If yes, how do I inter-convert them?

---

### EDIT

The following solution was given:

[image]

Comment: My feeling is that the integrand may be a typo, might be $\sin(x+t)$ (or something similar) and not $\sin(x+1)$, but I couldn’t know; however, per the problem as given, your approach above seems sound.

Comment: Judging from the solution, my feeling about is is right—the integrand is $f(t)\sin(x+t)$.

Comment: Yes. It turns out that the question must involve $\sin(x+t)$ and not $\sin(x+1)$(evident from the solution as well). Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = x^2 + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \sin(x+t) dt$$
differentiate twice wrt $x$
$$f''(x) = 2-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \sin(x+t) dt$$
but
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \sin(x+t) dt=f(x)-x^2$$
thus we get
$$f''(x)=2-f(x)+x^2$$
$$f(x) = x^2+a \cos (x)+b \sin (x)$$

Compute now
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \sin(x+t) dt=\frac{1}{4} \left(\left(\pi  a+2 b+\pi ^2-8\right) \sin (x)+(2 a+\pi  (b+4)-8) \cos (x)\right)$$
we know that $f(x)-x^2=a \cos (x)+b \sin (x)$ so we have
$$a \cos (x)+b \sin (x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\left(\pi  a+2 b+\pi ^2-8\right) \sin (x)+(2 a+\pi  (b+4)-8) \cos (x)\right)$$
which leads to the system of two linear equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 (2 a+\pi  (b+4)-8)=4a \\
 \pi  a+2 b+\pi ^2-8=4b \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$$a= -\frac{\pi ^3-16}{\pi ^2-4},\;b= -\frac{2 \left(3\pi^2-4\pi-8\right)}{\pi ^2-4}$$

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jack, the correcte IQ is
$$f(x)=x^2+\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(x+t) f(t) dt~~~~(1)$$
$$\implies f(x)=x^2+A \sin x+ B\cos x~~~~(2)$$, such that
$$A=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos t f(t) dt~~~~(3)$$
$$B=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin t f(t) dt~~~~(4)$$
Inserting (2) in (3) and (4), we get $A,B$ as vreported by the OP.